# How to prepare for IMO as a math beginner

Tags: self-learning

I always wanted to solve IMO papers, those always took grabbed my attention, I did some calculus (till basics of multivariable cal, in Khan academy!! (self-taught only)), but, I feel lost right now, I don't know what to proceed next, can someone pls help me (P.S - I am a 15-year-old, who knows only a small fraction of things......, where should I start ?)

Comment: See https://artofproblemsolving.com/ for a place with tons of resources.

Comment: You absolutely do not need calculus for the Mathematical Olympiads.

Comment: Oh.....then how to start all over?

Comment: on Art of Problem Solving, there's a (free) forum where lots of analogous questions have been asked before.  There's also (free) access to thousands of past contest problems and solutions, and jumping in and trying to solve problems is one of the best ways to get started with this sort of thing.

Comment: sure ! i will check them out !! thank you soo much !!

Comment: @Legendre !!! Thats website was soo cool !! I feel dumb for not finding that website !! Thank you soo much !!!!

Comment: Do you know some sites/books? , like where I can learn it directly, like lectures or books?

Comment: A list of competitions you can try in increasing order of difficulty are: AMC 8, AMC 10, AMC 12, AIME, USAJMO, USAMO.  What I might suggest is to try working through some of these past contests and see how you do.  When you find a point where you feel the contest is too difficult, you can then try to search for things along the lines of "how to improve at AMC 10" on AoPS.  The other thing I might recommend for gaining knowledge is the AoPS volumes I and II, I found them extremely well-written and helpful for preparing for contests from the AMC 10 to olympiads.

Comment: Wow !! That really helps a lot !!! I will try all of them! thank you sooo much !!!!!!! @Legendre